# How to get instance of activity in broadcast receiver in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am firing broadcast receiver from manifest. It works well. I am able to show dilog on the basis of action.

My problem statement was to create gesture on dilog which inflated from receiver. For creating gesturelistner it requires activity instance, but I am unable to cast context to activity.

As documentation says we unable to parse context to activity, it shows cast exception like ,android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

How can I cast Context to Activity at runtime in broadcast receiver at runtime?

Comment: `"for creating gesturelistner it requiers activity instance"` that is not true, `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` does not require any activity

Comment: Following code will help you http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html